# How can I display the values of the track bars?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want to be able to have it show the value of the each new track bar as the label but I am having some problems, if anyone is able to help can you explain as much as possible as I am pretty beginner level to this.

I tried this, simply setting the Label text to the value of the TrackBar.

```
private void AddBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the current count of controls in the panel, excluding the Add button
    int count = panel1.Controls.Count - 2;

    // Define the vertical spacing between controls
    int spacing = 30;

    // Create a TextBox dynamically
    TextBox TextBox = new TextBox
    {
        Name = "textBox" + count,
        Width = 200,
        Font = new Font("Roboto Bk", 13),
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(105, 80 + spacing * count - 30),
    };

    // Create a TrackBar dynamically
    TrackBar TrackBar = new TrackBar
    {
        Name = "trackBar" + count,
        Width = 250,
        Minimum = 0,
        Maximum = 100,
        TickFrequency = 5,
        TickStyle = TickStyle.Both,
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(80, 80 + spacing * count),
    };

    // Create a Label dynamically
    Label Label = new Label
    {
        Name = "label" + count,
        Text = "£" + TrackBar.Value.ToString(),
        Font = new Font("Roboto Bk", 15),
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(330, 90 + spacing * count),
    };

    // Add controls to panel1
    panel1.Controls.Add(TextBox);
    panel1.Controls.Add(TrackBar);
    panel1.Controls.Add(Label);
}
```

Comment: Ditch the Panel, create a UserControl that contains those child Controls. Then create a new UserControl instance when needed and add this UserControl to a FlowLayoutPanel (or TableLayoutPanel, depending on the Layout you're after). The UserControl can have public properties / events that allows to get / set values / react to value changes of the internal child Controls

Comment: To display the value of the TrackBar as its label, you need to handle the ValueChanged event of the TrackBar. When the value changes, you'll update the text of the associated Label. Add an event handler for the ValueChanged event of the TrackBar when you create it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binding for that.

Here is you fonction with bindings, but as @Jimi said, I recommend you to create and use [custom controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls-design/overview?view=netdesktop-8.0)

```
 private void AddBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // Get the current count of controls in the panel, excluding the Add button
     int count = panel1.Controls.Count - 2;

     // Define the vertical spacing between controls
     int spacing = 30;

     // Create a TextBox dynamically
     TextBox TextBox = new TextBox
     {
         Name = "textBox" + count,
         Width = 200,
         Font = new Font("Roboto Bk", 13),
         Location = new System.Drawing.Point(105, 80 + spacing * count - 30),
     };

     // Create a TrackBar dynamically
     TrackBar TrackBar = new TrackBar
     {
         Name = "trackBar" + count,
         Width = 250,
         Minimum = 0,
         Maximum = 100,
         TickFrequency = 5,
         TickStyle = TickStyle.Both,
         Location = new System.Drawing.Point(80, 80 + spacing * count),
     };

     // Create a Label dynamically
     Label label = new Label
     {
         Name = "label" + count,
         Font = new Font("Roboto Bk", 15),
         Location = new System.Drawing.Point(330, 90 + spacing * count),
     };

     //Bind the TrackBar to the label Text
     var binding = new Binding("Text", TrackBar, "Value")
     {
         FormattingEnabled = true,
         FormatString = "£0"
     };
     label.DataBindings.Add(binding);
     
     // Add controls to panel1
     panel1.Controls.Add(TextBox);
     panel1.Controls.Add(TrackBar);
     panel1.Controls.Add(label);
 }
```